# TextView , Text is grayed out

Tags: android

Text in the textView seems like it is grayed out.

I want so set the text color as when you click textView then It seems in black color as it is enabled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For changing the text color of TextView you need to set its textColor property.

In XML file you can do like :

```
<TextView
            android:text="Some text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#ffff00"
            android:background="#ff0000"
            />
```

Programatically you can set TextColor and its Background in TextView using :

```
  text_view.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
  text_view.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
```

Hope this helps. !

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
    text.setBackgroundColor(56565);
    text.setEnabled(true);
```

it will helpful for u

Answer (score 0):

you can change just alpha value of the textview like as following

from https://gist.github.com/Skamp/1330169

```
final ColorStateList colors = textview.getTextColors();
...
    textview.setTextColor(colors.withAlpha(255));
```